# how to do one hot encoding to predefined column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform one hot encoding to one column in my data. The column may looks like this:

```
    app   
0   a       
1   b      
2   c      
3   a
```

I've performed:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['app'])
    app_a   app_b   app_c
0     1        0    0
1     0        1    0
2     0        0    1
3     1        0    0
```

But in reality, the app column can contain 'd' value, in my data to train I don't have it. So what I want is to add `app_d` after perform `get_dummies` without 'd' value in my data.

Is there any code can one hot encoding form my simple data above to predefined columns? What I want looks like this:

```
 app_a  app_b app_c  app_d
     0    1     0   0    0
     1    0     1   0    0
     2    0     0   1    0
     3    1     0   0    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting your column to [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) dtype and specify the `categories` argument:

```
df['app'] = pd.Categorical(df['app'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

pd.get_dummies(df['app'], prefix='app')
```

[out]

```
   app_a  app_b  app_c  app_d
0      1      0      0      0
1      0      1      0      0
2      0      0      1      0
3      1      0      0      0
```

Alternatively you could convert to `Categorical` type and use the [`cat.add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) accessor method to update `categories` after the fact:

```
df['app'] = pd.Categorical(df['app'])

df['app'].cat.add_categories(['d'], inplace=True)
```